# How to consume POST call where parameter is of type application/x-www-form-urlencoded in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a rest call,where it requires one parameter empid to be passed of type

```
 application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

[image]

Iam trying to consume that using the following code.But the value is getting passed as undefined to the restcall

```
 function searchEmployee(employeeid){
        var empEndpoint = 'http://localhost:3001/searchemp';
        var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
        http.open('POST',empEndpoint,true);
        http.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        var empid = employeeid;
        http.send(empid) ;
    }
```

Please can someone point out the mistake and help me how to POST that in proper format.

***Edit added server code

```
app.post('/searchemp',function(req,res){
   reqbody = req.body.empid;
   console.log(reqbody,"reqbody");
   var empdetails =con.query('SELECT * FROM tasktable WHERE Empid =?',reqbody,
     function(err,rows){
      if(err) throw err;

       console.log('EMP Data received from Db:\n');
      res.send(rows);
});
});
```

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser You need to add this in order to parse body data. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

That depends on where you call the function `searchEmployee` from and how you do it.

as `var empid = employeeid;` and `employeeid` is the first parameter of your function you should call `searchEmployee` with an appropriate parameter such as `2474`.

so your should call it like that:

```html
searchEmployee(2474);

function searchEmployee(employeeid){
        var empEndpoint = 'http://localhost:3001/searchemp';
        var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
        http.open('POST',empEndpoint,true);
        http.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
        var params = `empid=${empid}`;
        http.send(params);            
    }
```

maybe this helps: http://www.openjs.com/articles/ajax_xmlhttp_using_post.php

```js
var url = "get_data.php";
var params = "lorem=ipsum&name=binny";
http.open("POST", url, true);

//Send the proper header information along with the request
http.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
http.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
http.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");

http.onreadystatechange = function() {//Call a function when the state changes.
 if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
  alert(http.responseText);
 }
}
http.send(params);
```

especially this should be the way to go:

`var params = "lorem=ipsum&name=binny";`

your equivalent should look like this:

```js
var params = `empid=${empid}`;
http.send(params);
```

Comment: @driedel.Yes Iam doing the same.but empid is reaching as undefined to my node js restcall

Comment: maybe this helps:

Comment: @driendel...Ive added that in my question ..u can check now..In the first console Im getting undefined